# How to use group by to compute Max(Count(Columnname)) from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, having-clause

How to find data for the following query

[Original Source](http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php#answer_ref) question 89

Table structure:
**Product(Maker, Model, Type)**

**Edit**
[Use sqlfiddle for schema](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ba8/1)

Task:
**Find out those makers who have the most number of models in the
Product table as well as those who have the least number of models.
Output: maker, number of models**

Hints given in question are `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `IN`

I tried various ways to find this basically what I came up with is I need to use `Max(COUNT(model))`

Result should be

```
maker   qty 
A        7 --max
C        1 --min
```

One solution I came up with is

```
select maker, count(ps.model) as Count from product as ps
group by ps.maker
having count(ps.model) in
(
select max(cnt) from (select count(model) as cnt from product group by maker)t
union
select min(cnt) from (select count(model) as cnt from product group by maker)t
)
```

Is there any other way.

Comment: @marc_s usign http://www.sql-ex.ru to practice where I got this question. So can't say about database but this is a simple RDBMS question

Comment: You can also practice your SQL skills and check if it is RDBMS-agnostic, try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @MichaelBuen: For this whole new dataset needs to be created before starting practice. But sql-ex provides prebuilt database to practice select query.

Comment: @MichaelBuen: Added sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, you can simplify it with this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ba8/7

```
with counts as
(
  select maker, count(ps.model) as Count from product as ps
  group by ps.maker
)
select cx.*
from counts cx
join
(
  select min(count) as lo, max(count) as hi
  from counts
) as hi_lo 
on cx.count = hi_lo.lo or cx.count = hi_lo.hi;
```

Comment: Just added [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ba8/1). Schema is little different. I don't have counts precalculated. It needs to be calculated on the basis of maker.

Comment: Thanks..I didn't thought of this solution. Rather i was thinking to use TOP 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 maker, COUNT(*) C
    FROM product
    GROUP BY maker
    ORDER BY C DESC
) Q1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 maker, COUNT(*) C
    FROM product
    GROUP BY maker
    ORDER BY C
) Q2;
```

...or if you are fond of CTEs...

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT maker, COUNT(*) C
    FROM product
    GROUP BY maker
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY C DESC
) Q1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY C
) Q2;
```

...as demonstrated in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25ba8/51).